# How to avoid jagged ellipses on HTML canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, antialiasing

I'm trying to draw a circle on my canvas, but it's coming out jagged.

Here's how I'm drawing the ellipse:

```
ctx.ellipse(currX + room.location[0], currY + room.location[1], radius, radius, 0, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
```

Here's what I've tried to fix the issue with:

```
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
ctx.imageSmoothingQuality = 'high';
ctx.filter = 'best';
ctx.antialias = 'subpixel';
```

[image: jagged elipse]

Comment: use SVG to get smooth curves

Comment: https://www.educba.com/html-svg/

Answer (score 0):

If you just need text inside a circle, you can use `border-radius`

```css
.room {
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: tahoma;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2px;
}

#content {
  height: 30px;
  width: 60px;
  background-color: yellow; 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
   <div class="room">21</div>
   <div class="room">33</div>
</div>
```